# Testing code that uses an IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, qunit, intersection-observer

I have a JavaScript component in my application that handles infinite scroll pagination, and i'm trying to rewrite it to use the `IntersectionObserver`, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/intersectionobserver), however I'm having issues in testing it.

Is there a way to drive the behavior of the observer in a QUnit test, i.e. to trigger the observer callback with some entries described in my tests?

A possible solution I have come up with is to expose the callback function in the component's prototype and to invoke it directly in my test, something like this:

```
InfiniteScroll.prototype.observerCallback = function(entries) {
    //handle the infinite scroll
}

InfiniteScroll.prototype.initObserver = function() {
    var io = new IntersectionObserver(this.observerCallback);
    io.observe(someElements);
}

//In my test
var component = new InfiniteScroll();
component.observerCallback(someEntries);
//Do some assertions about the state after the callback has been executed
```

I don't really like this approach since it's exposing the fact that the component uses an `IntersectionObserver` internally, which is an implementation detail that in my opinion should not be visible to client code, so is there any better way to test this (ideally not using jQuery)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's another alternative based on previous answers, you can run it inside the `beforeEach` methods, or at the beginning of the `.test.js` file.

You could also pass parameters to the `setupIntersectionObserverMock` to mock the `observe` and/or `unobserve` methods to spy on them with a `jest.fn()` mock function.

```js
/**
 * Utility function that mocks the `IntersectionObserver` API. Necessary for components that rely
 * on it, otherwise the tests will crash. Recommended to execute inside `beforeEach`.
 * @param intersectionObserverMock - Parameter that is sent to the `Object.defineProperty`
 * overwrite method. `jest.fn()` mock functions can be passed here if the goal is to not only
 * mock the intersection observer, but its methods.
 */
export function setupIntersectionObserverMock({
  root = null,
  rootMargin = '',
  thresholds = [],
  disconnect = () => null,
  observe = () => null,
  takeRecords = () => [],
  unobserve = () => null,
} = {}) {
  class MockIntersectionObserver {
    constructor() {
      this.root = root;
      this.rootMargin = rootMargin;
      this.thresholds = thresholds;
      this.disconnect = disconnect;
      this.observe = observe;
      this.takeRecords = takeRecords;
      this.unobserve = unobserve;
    }
  }

  Object.defineProperty(window, 'IntersectionObserver', {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value: MockIntersectionObserver
  });

  Object.defineProperty(global, 'IntersectionObserver', {
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    value: MockIntersectionObserver
  });
}
```

And for TypeScript:

```
/**
 * Utility function that mocks the `IntersectionObserver` API. Necessary for components that rely
 * on it, otherwise the tests will crash. Recommended to execute inside `beforeEach`.
 * @param intersectionObserverMock - Parameter that is sent to the `Object.defineProperty`
 * overwrite method. `jest.fn()` mock functions can be passed here if the goal is to not only
 * mock the intersection observer, but its methods.
 */
export function setupIntersectionObserverMock({
  root = null,
  rootMargin = '',
  thresholds = [],
  disconnect = () => null,
  observe = () => null,
  takeRecords = () => [],
  unobserve = () => null,
} = {}): void {
  class MockIntersectionObserver implements IntersectionObserver {
    readonly root: Element | null = root;
    readonly rootMargin: string = rootMargin;
    readonly thresholds: ReadonlyArray < number > = thresholds;
    disconnect: () => void = disconnect;
    observe: (target: Element) => void = observe;
    takeRecords: () => IntersectionObserverEntry[] = takeRecords;
    unobserve: (target: Element) => void = unobserve;
  }

  Object.defineProperty(
    window,
    'IntersectionObserver', {
      writable: true,
      configurable: true,
      value: MockIntersectionObserver
    }
  );

  Object.defineProperty(
    global,
    'IntersectionObserver', {
      writable: true,
      configurable: true,
      value: MockIntersectionObserver
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Great one, just save my day.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Consider adding the disconnect method as well.

Comment: Good idea @sibasishm, just added the methods from the IntersectionObserver API found in the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver

Comment: how do you test IO callback with this approach?

Answer (score 60):

None of the posted answered worked for me because of our configuration of TypeScript and React (tsx) we're using. Here's what finally worked:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  // IntersectionObserver isn't available in test environment
  const mockIntersectionObserver = jest.fn();
  mockIntersectionObserver.mockReturnValue({
    observe: () => null,
    unobserve: () => null,
    disconnect: () => null
  });
  window.IntersectionObserver = mockIntersectionObserver;
});
```

Comment: Worked for me too in React Typescript project. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also worked for me in Angular / Jest.

Comment: Works with React / Typescript / Vitest

Comment: worked for me as well!

Comment: The only one that works for me too! React / TypeScript / Jest.

Answer (score 31):

In your *jest.setup.js* file, mock the IntersectionObserver with the following implementation:

```
global.IntersectionObserver = class IntersectionObserver {
  constructor() {}

  disconnect() {
    return null;
  }

  observe() {
    return null;
  }

  takeRecords() {
    return null;
  }

  unobserve() {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Instead of using the [Jest Setup File](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-testing-jest/), you can do this mocking also directly in your tests or in your beforeAll,beforeEach blocks.

Comment: Is there a TypeScript-friendly version of this? It works, but I get warnings... i.e. on `global.IntersectionObserver`: `Type 'typeof IntersectionObserver' is not assignable to type '{ new (callback: IntersectionObserverCallback, options?: IntersectionObserverInit | undefined): IntersectionObserver; prototype: IntersectionObserver; }'.`

Answer (score 15):

Same problem in 2019 this is how I solved it:

```
import ....

describe('IntersectionObserverMokTest', () => {
  ...
  const observeMock = {
    observe: () => null,
    disconnect: () => null // maybe not needed
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    (<any> window).IntersectionObserver = () => observeMock;

    ....
  }));


  it(' should run the Test without throwing an error for the IntersectionObserver', () => {
    ...
  })
});
```

So I create a mock object, with the `observe` (and `disconnect`) method and overwrite the `IntersectionObserver` on the window object. Depending on your usage, you might have to overwrite other functions (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Browser_compatibility )

The code is inspired by https://gist.github.com/ianmcnally/4b68c56900a20840b6ca840e2403771c but doesn't use `jest`

Answer (score 4):

I tested it like this for Jest+Typescript

```
         type CB = (arg1: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => void;
            class MockedObserver {
              cb: CB;
              options: IntersectionObserverInit;
              elements: HTMLElement[];
            
              constructor(cb: CB, options: IntersectionObserverInit) {
                this.cb = cb;
                this.options = options;
                this.elements = [];
              }
            
              unobserve(elem: HTMLElement): void {
                this.elements = this.elements.filter((en) => en !== elem);
              }
            
              observe(elem: HTMLElement): void {
                this.elements = [...new Set(this.elements.concat(elem))];
              }
            
              disconnect(): void {
                this.elements = [];
              }
            
              fire(arr: IntersectionObserverEntry[]): void {
                this.cb(arr);
              }
            }
        
        function traceMethodCalls(obj: object | Function, calls: any = {}) {
          const handler: ProxyHandler<object | Function> = {
            get(target, propKey, receiver) {
              const targetValue = Reflect.get(target, propKey, receiver);
              if (typeof targetValue === 'function') {
                return function (...args: any[]) {
                  calls[propKey] = (calls[propKey] || []).concat(args);
                  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
                  // @ts-ignore
                  return targetValue.apply(this, args);
                };
              } else {
                return targetValue;
              }
            },
          };
          return new Proxy(obj, handler);
        }
```

And in test

```
describe('useIntersectionObserver', () => {
  let observer: any;
  let mockedObserverCalls: { [k: string]: any } = {};

  beforeEach(() => {
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'IntersectionObserver', {
      writable: true,
      value: jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementation(function TrackMock(
          cb: CB,
          options: IntersectionObserverInit
        ) {
          observer = traceMethodCalls(
            new MockedObserver(cb, options),
            mockedObserverCalls
          );

          return observer;
        }),
    });
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    observer = null;
    mockedObserverCalls = {};
  });

    test('should do something', () => {
      const mockedObserver = observer as unknown as MockedObserver;
    
      const entry1 = {
        target: new HTMLElement(),
        intersectionRatio: 0.7,
      };
      // fire CB
      mockedObserver.fire([entry1 as unknown as IntersectionObserverEntry]);

      // possibly need to make test async/wait for see changes
      //  await waitForNextUpdate();
      //  await waitForDomChanges();
      //  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));


      // Check calls to observer
      expect(mockedObserverCalls.disconnect).toEqual([]);
      expect(mockedObserverCalls.observe).toEqual([]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ingenious!! This should be the answer! Thank you so much.  I was looking for solution for a week already! My savior!   `observer.fire()` feature is so much elegant.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem with a setup based on vue-cli. I ended up using a mix of the answers I saw above:

```
   const mockIntersectionObserver = class {
    constructor() {}
    observe() {}
    unobserve() {}
    disconnect() {}
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    window.IntersectionObserver = mockIntersectionObserver;
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar stack issue as @Kevin Brotcke, except using their solution resulted in a further TypeScript error:

> Function expression, which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.

Here's a tweaked solution that worked for me:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    // IntersectionObserver isn't available in test environment
    const mockIntersectionObserver = jest.fn()
    mockIntersectionObserver.mockReturnValue({
      observe: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(null),
      unobserve: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(null),
      disconnect: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(null)
    })
    window.IntersectionObserver = mockIntersectionObserver
  })
```

Comment: Hi, how can I change this if I want to see what triggered my mockIntersectionObserver? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @MadhavThakker I'm not sure I understand the question. You should be testing the trigger implicitly, you shouldn't need to test what it is? As in, your test should have an action that calls the intersection obeserver, and then you would test to ensure that the mock has been called once (or however many times you would expect).

(might require a new SO question)

Comment: Makes sense. I am able to verify that my mock observe jest function is being called once. Can I also rerender the GUI component accordingly as if it was being rendered in the browser? Basically, check if the component that the intersection observer is observing is not on screen, if so, then rerender that component back on screen?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure, you'd need to test it to find out. But remember that the JSDOM is not a 1:1 representation of the browser DOM. My best guess is that this kind of trigger may not be supported.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use the polyfill that is provided by this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/intersection-observer

A simple import in your `setupFiles` would do

```
import 'intersection-observer';
```

If you still use commonjs

```
require('intersection-observer');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my test I actually wanted to *trigger* the callback function passed to new `IntersectionObserver`. Extending above examples, I would first write my own class that would store `callback` in a static variable:

```js
class MockIntersectionObserver implements IntersectionObserver {
  static callback: IntersectionObserverCallback;
  options: IntersectionObserverInit | undefined;
  constructor(callback: IntersectionObserverCallback, options?: IntersectionObserverInit) {
    MockIntersectionObserver.callback = callback;
    this.options = options;
  }

  root: Document | Element | null = null;
  rootMargin: string = '';
  thresholds: readonly number[] = [];
  disconnect = vi.fn();
  observe = vi.fn();
  takeRecords = vi.fn();
  unobserve = vi.fn();

  static triggerCallback(entries: any) {
    MockIntersectionObserver.callback(entries, {
      disconnect: vi.fn(),
      observe: vi.fn(),
      takeRecords: vi.fn(),
      unobserve: vi.fn(),
      root: null,
      rootMargin: '',
      thresholds: [],
    });
  }
}
window.IntersectionObserver = MockIntersectionObserver;
```

Inside the test I would manually trigger the callback like so:

```js
MockIntersectionObserver.triggerCallback([{ isIntersecting: true }]);
```