# How do I mock the IntersectionObserver API in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I've read all of the relevant questions on this topic, and I realize this will probably be marked as a duplicate, but I simply cannot for the life of me figure out how to get this working.

I have this simple function that lazily loads elements:

```js
export default function lazyLoad(targets, onIntersection) {
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, self) => {
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        onIntersection(entry.target);
        self.unobserve(entry.target);
      }
    });
  });

  document.querySelectorAll(targets).forEach((target) => observer.observe(target));
  return observer;
}
```

Example usage:

```js
lazyLoad('.lazy-img', (img) => {
  const pictureElement = img.parentElement;
  const source = pictureElement.querySelector('.lazy-source');

  source.srcset = source.getAttribute('data-srcset');
  img.src = img.getAttribute('data-src');
});
```

Now, I'm trying to test the `lazyLoad` function using jest, but I obviously need to mock IntersectionObserver since it's a browser API, not a native JavaScript one.

The following works for testing the `observe` method:

```js
let observe;
let unobserve;

beforeEach(() => {
  observe = jest.fn();
  unobserve = jest.fn();

  window.IntersectionObserver = jest.fn(() => ({
    observe,
    unobserve,
  }));
});

describe('lazyLoad utility', () => {
  it('calls observe on each target', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      const target = document.createElement('img');
      target.className = 'lazy-img';
      document.body.appendChild(target);
    }

    lazyLoad(
      '.lazy-img',
      jest.fn(() => {})
    );

    expect(observe).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
  });
});
```

But I also want to test the `.isIntersecting` logic, where the callback fires... Except I don't know how to do that. How can I test intersections with jest?

Comment: Pass it as an argument.

Comment: @Adam Could you please clarify what you mean? What should I pass as an argument? Thanks!

Comment: `lazyLoad(targets,onIntersection,observer = IntersectionObserver)`

Comment: [This could also be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44249985/js-testing-code-that-uses-an-intersectionobserver)

Comment: @Adam Thanks! Unfortunately, I already read that SO post and it did not help me. I'm mainly stuck on how to simulate the `.isIntersecting` check for an IntersectionObserver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mocking stuff is so easy when you pass it as an argument:

```js
export default function lazyLoad(targets, onIntersection, observerClass = IntersectionObserver) {
  const observer = new observerClass(...)
  ...
}


// test file
let entries = [];
const observeFn = jest.fn();
const unobserveFn = jest.fn()
class MockObserver {
  constructor(fn) {
    fn(entries,this);
  }

  observe() { observeFn() }
  unobserve() { unobserveFn() }
}

test('...',() => {
   // set `entries` to be something so you can mock it
   entries = ...something
   lazyLoad('something',jest.fn(),MockObserver);
});
```

Comment: This makes sense, thank you! I didn't think to use dependency injection like this. I assume I'll need `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`, though, right? Because I can't do `observe = jest.fn()`.

Comment: @AleksandrH I changed the syntax, the dependency injection was the main  idea, for the rest of the spies just do whatever you need to do.

Comment: @AleksandrH let this be one of those standout moments for how to write testable code - whatever you need to mock, just make it an argument.

Comment: It sure was a lightbulb moment for me, thank you! My tests are much easier to write now for this utility.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use mockObserver mentioned above and mock in window.

```
window.IntersetionObserver = mockObserver
```

And you don't necessary need to pass observer in component props.

The important point to test if entries isIntesecting is to mock IntersectionObserver as class like mentioned above.